# Why was "Caesar" borrowed for the imperial title in German rather than "Augustus"?

Tags: language, titles

After Caesar (which simply happened to be his family name) Octavius took the title Augustus which means better, more, **augmented**. And most Roman emperors and strong men took the title Augustus thereafter. Their second in command was given the title Caesar/Kaiser. Please correct me if this description is flawed!

But then why didn't the Germans use the title Augustus rather than Caesar for their word for Emperor?

Comment: Augustus, despite his name and all his prowess, was, at the time, less influential than Caesar. Plus, for Napoleon at least, it was more or less sensed to choose Caesar (Republican, assassinated before he could do what he wanted etc) against a title like Augustus (emperor, "betrayed" Marc-Anthony etc) which was also used by an old French King. (Phillip the second). He was first Consul before he was emperor, and do you know another first Consul ? Perhaps Caesar?

Comment: The German emperors, including Francis II, did in fact took the title Augustus. The standard style of the Holy Roman Emperors was [*Dei Gratia Romanorum Imperator Semper* ***Augustus***](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/26827/4935). According to Wikipedia, from 1804, Francis II likewise was styled "by the Grace of God elected Roman Emperor, **ever Augustus**, hereditary Emperor of Austria" - i.e., he simplly taked Emperor of Austria onto the usual title of the German emperors. Given the above, can you please clarify your question? Are you perhaps questioning the claim on Wikipedia?

Comment: @Semaphore Ah, so he formally DID! I can only blame that it is lesser known to the general public. Why wasn't Augustus used as a public title instead of Caesar? In times when people relevant to politics knew about their histories. Why Kaiser Wilhelm II instead of August Wilhelm II, for example.

Comment: Ah, I see what the underlying question is. The title was Imperator (emperor); but the German word for that was *Kaiser*. The same is also true of several other languages e.g. Russian (Tsar) or Turkish (Kayser). If I am understanding you correctly, your real question would seem to be, *why was Caesar borrowed for the imperial title in German rather than Augustus (or Imperator)?* I think that is a great question if you would edit your post to focus on that. Thanks!

Comment: @Semaphore Done! It is sometimes difficult to even formulate a question that could bridge the gap of knowledge. And did Napoleon too name himself Augustus? Why didn't this word become popular? Wouldn't it literally be "better" to do so, rather than to just be a second rate Kaiser?

Comment: @LocalFluff I want to stress again that the German imperial title was *Imperator*, **not "Caesar"**. The German translation for the Latin imperator happened to be kaiser, but the actual title was in Latin, not German. The German for "Caesar" was Caesar and was once revived for Henry VI (before he became Emperor) during the Middle Ages. As for Napoleon, he was likewise also styled Empereur, which was the French for Imperator, not "Caesar".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Caesar came first, and Caesar remained.

We observe that the first really big contact between Germanic tribes and Rome took place when Gaius Iulius Caesar was [campaigning 'in Gaul'.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar#Conquest_of_Gaul)

We observe also that under his adopted nephew Octavian the largest forays of Rome into Germanic lands was undertaken, bordering on colonising and provincialising Germany up to the Elbe river. The well known [Battle of the Teutoburg Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Teutoburg_Forest) took place when Octavian was imperator, when *we* call him Augustus.

But what was his name then?

> [Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus#Name)
>   As a consequence of Roman customs, society, and personal preference, Augustus (/ɔːˈɡʌstəs, əˈɡʌs-/; Classical Latin: [awˈɡʊstʊs]) was known by many names throughout his life:
>
> - Gaius Octavius Thurinus (/ɒkˈteɪviəs/): He received his birth name, after his biological father, in 63 BC. "Gaius" was his praenomen, "Octavius" was his nomen, and "Thurinus" was his cognomen. Later, his rival Mark Antony used the name "Thurinus" as an insult, to which Augustus replied, surprised that "using his old name was thought to be an insult".[5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlemagne#Imperial_title)[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlemagne#Imperial_title)
> - Gaius Julius **Caesar:** After he was adopted by Julius Caesar, he adopted Caesar's name in accordance with Roman naming conventions. While he dropped all references to the gens Octavia, people colloquially added the epithet Octavianus to his legal name, either to differentiate him from his adoptive father or to highlight his more modest origins. Modern historians refer to him using the anglicized form "Octavian" (/ɒkˈteɪviən/) between 44 BC and 27 BC.
> - Gaius Julius **Caesar** Divi Filius: Two years after his adoption, he founded the Temple of Caesar additionally adding the title Divi Filius ("Son of the Divine") to his name in attempt to strengthen his political ties to Caesar's former soldiers, following the deification of Caesar.
> - Imperator **Caesar** Divi Filius: From 38 BC, Octavian opted to use Imperator, the title by which troops hailed their leader after military success. His name is roughly translated as "Commander Caesar, Son of the Divine".
> - Imperator **Caesar** Divi Filius Augustus: Following his 31 BC defeat of Mark Antony and Cleopatra, partly on his own insistence, the Roman Senate granted him the additional name, "Augustus", which he added to his previous names thereafter. Historians use this name to refer to him from 27 BC until his death in AD 14.

Augustus successor then renamed himself Tiberius Julius Caesar.

That means that from an almost equivalent to 'first contact' for the next 3 generations, the Germanic tribes when asking legionariries "who's your boss?" they would have heard at least some kind of "Caesar!".

In both cases, we also take note that the persons bearing that name would react quite peculiar when asked by anyone: "Are you a king?" Namely with "ONonononono, I am not a king, I am something different, the restorer of the res publicas!"

That it was around that time the name was borrowed into Germanic languages is evidenced by linguistics and language development. Caesar/Kaiser is one of the [oldest](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kaiser) Latin loanwords into Germanic languages. Loaning must have happened around that time that the mono-archicical biggest honcho of the Romans was always called some form of Caesar as the *history of the sound* of the German word proves: Shortly after this time the Latin language itself changed and the German loanword preserved the older sound:

> Probably the oldest German loan word from Latin is Kaiser. The word goes back to the family name Caesar or its most famous bearer *Gaius Iulius Caesar* (100-44 B.C.) and was used as title under the following rulers. The word first came into Germanic and then further into German. The ahd. keisur (also -or, -ar) is probably also still used as title, but at the same time already as deonomastikon, as an appellative derived from the name with the meaning *ruler. Similarly, under the impression of an overpowering ruler, the Slavs later gave the name of Charlemagne, i.e. ahd. Karal / Karl, borrowed and used as ruler designation (Russian. король, Czech. král, Polish. król etc. for *King). But also to the Russian. царь *Zar is based on Caesar, it is a loan from got. kaisar, which goes back to Caesar via greek καῖσαρ . The sound laws allow here an approximate dating of the loan of Caesar into Germanic: It could not take place later than in the 2nd century, because until then the Diphthong ae was still spoken in Caesar, which also appears in ahd. keisur or got. kaisar; also the k- pronunciation was still preserved in the sound of Caesar, only in the 6th/7th century was k- palatalized, thus spoken as [ts].
>   <sub>–– Kurt Gärtner: ["Lehnübersetzung und Lehnbedeutung vs. Lehnwort: Zu den Entlehnungen aus dem Lateinischen und Französischen in das mittelalterliche Deutsch"](http://edition-open-access.de/studies/10/6/index.html), in Jens Braarvig & Markham J. Geller (Eds): "Studies in Multilingualism, Lingua Franca and Lingua Sacra", Edition Open Access: Berlin, 2018.</sub>

Thus the oldest German loanword was well established when the Romans started to devise ever more complicated  stylings for their 'emperor'. This more legalistic terminology of the Romans in Latin was then indeed adopted as well by the Germnic tribes that tried their luck at *renovatio imperii*. [Charlemange as emperor was titled:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlemagne#Imperial_title)

> Karolus serenissimus Augustus a Deo coronatus magnus pacificus imperator Romanum gubernans imperium

That illustrates that Germans have really borrowed *all* available titles:
Caesar, Imperator, Augustus.

While Augustus as a title is only used in Latin forms of titles and as a word declined in meaning and understandability, Caesar/Kaiser remained a very scarce given name. But August became common from the 14th century onward and besides also signifying a month it also took on a row of [unfortunate](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BC%C3%9Faugust) [connotations](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~ein%20dummer%20August).  Imperator remained a decidedly foreign word. Kaiser was the first, the most enduring, the most popular of these forms. And when a German speaking peasant would ask what the various long Latin titles (containing some form of Augustus) of Germanic emperors would come to mean, the answer would again be "Kaiser!"

That means that in medieval times the full title was a legal thing, and as such Latin dominated. Only the colloquial translation into the tongue of the people was still the old germanised word. That this got somewhat out of hand in being complicated is evidenced by the long-form of the titles of the kaisers of Austria. 'Long' as in [three pages long.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_title_of_the_Emperor_of_Austria)

When the German Empire was founded in 1871 the nationalist mood and complicated power politics within the Reich and in regard to Austria called for a simpler solution. A title that would still allow kings within Germany but also elevate the Prussian Hohenzollern king above the others. Thus the function of [Federal President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundespr%C3%A4sidium) of the Reich got named with the word for 'biggest honcho in the empire' from 2000 years ago: Kaiser.

Comment: Excellent post, this should be the accepted answer - because Germans borrowed Caesar before Augustus came into vogue.

Comment: Very interesting and compelling! I suppose that the name Gustav is derived from Augustus. Gustav has been used by many Swedish kings the last 500 years, including the current one. So in a way I suppose Augustus has remained a title of a nation's leader. (In my own home country, and I was the one asking why it is NOT used as a title, duh) Although I think it was just a coincidence that Gustav Vasa happened to be named Gustav.

Comment: @LocalFluff Augustus and [Gustav](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gustav) do not share anything etymologically? But for Swedish kings' names, there is more to be found in the parallel of 'mighty king [Karl](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Karl)' (Charlemagne, in his own sounds probably more like karal) and the word for king in Slavic languages *[korol](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/karl)*.

Comment: You have neglected that in 1871, when William I became Emperor of Germany, he was the ***second*** "Kaiser" of German-speaking peoples - there already being a Kaiser in Vienna. The adoption of the same title in Berlin was in many ways to emphasize the equality of the two sovereigns.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens On purpose, disposing of it with a half-sentence in 2nd-last para. If you feel it more important for the Q&A that Willy I became **German Emperor** (btw: *not:* Emperor of Germany!) in relation to l'Empereur Napoleon *and* Francis (plus issue), please suggest an edit. (It's really complicated to adequately find and then display correctly the sensibilities involved. They are quite alien.)

Answer (score 3):

Why do people assume that the title of Roman Emperors was a single word?

Is President Trump's title "President" or "President of the United States"?  Since the title is abbreviated POTUs I would guess it is a phrase.

> The president of the United States (POTUS)[B] is the head of state and head of government of the United States of America. The president directs the executive branch of the federal government and is the commander-in-chief of the United States Armed Forces.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_United_States[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_United_States)

So Wikipedia seems to think the title is a phrase.

Is the title of Elizabeth II a single word or a phrase?

Since 1953 her title in the United Kingdom has had an English version and a Latin version, which are not, repeat not, exact translations:

> In English: Elizabeth the Second, by the Grace of God of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of Her other Realms and Territories Queen, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith[18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_titles_and_honours_of_Elizabeth_II)
>
> In Latin: Elizabeth II, Dei Gratia Britanniarum Regnorumque Suorum Ceterorum Regina, Consortionis Populorum Princeps, Fidei Defensor[19]
>   Oceania

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_titles_and_honours_of_Elizabeth_II[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_titles_and_honours_of_Elizabeth_II)

So many present titles are phrases.  Some may object that by "title" they specifically mean the single word that describes the rank or position or function of the leader, and not the complete phrase that describes both the type of leadership and also the group that is led.

Even accepting that argument, there are plenty of examples of ranks, positions, or functions that are described by phrases and not by single words.

For example, "Chairman of the Board of Directors of General Motors", "Chairman of the Presidium of the Supreme Soviet of the Union of Soviet Socialistic Republics", "Grand Duke of Lithuania", "Vice Admiral", "Field Marshal", "First Class Boy", "Grand Prince of Kiev", "Grand Master of the Teutonic Knights", "Cardinal Deacon", "*Nagusa Nagast*" meaning "King of Kings", etc., etc.

The early Roman emperors used a number of separate powers, titles, and honors.  Their main titles included *Imperator*, *Caesar*, *Augustus*, and *Princeps*.

There are examples of an *Imperator Caesar Augustus* having authority over a lesser ruler or designated successor with the title of *Imperator Caesar*, so one could say that in the Roman Empire *Imperator Caesar Augustus* meant "emperor", or "senior emperor", and *Imperator Caesar* meant "emperor's heir" or "junior emperor".

Therefore, I am somewhat skeptical that a single Latin word meant "emperor", and tend to think that the three word phrase *Imperator Caesar Augustus* meant emperor.

The titles used by the Holy Roman Emperors varied t lot over time.

By about 1190 the title of a man elected emperor but not yet crowned in Rome by the pope was:

> Romanorum Rex semper augustus

"King of the Romans always Emperor/Imperial".

And after being crowned in Rome by the Pope the title became:

> Romanorum Imperator et semper augustus

"Emperor of the Romans and always Emperor/Imperial".

In the later middle ages *semper augustus* was mistranslated in the German versions of the title.

> Romischer kayser zu allen zeyten merer des reichs

There Caesar instead of *imperator* or *augustus*, or all three together, is translated into German as *kaiser*, and *semper augustus*, meaning "always emperor" or "always imperial",  is mistranslated into German as *zu allen zeyten merer des reichs*, meaning "in all times enlarger of the realm", or "perpetual enlarger of the empire".

The last major change in the imperial title came when emperors stopped going to Rome to be crowned and took the imperial title immediately after election and coronation in Germany.

In Latin:

> Electus Romanorum Imperator semper Augustus, ac 
>   Germaniae... Rex,

"Elected Emperor of the Romans, Always Emperor (or always Imperial), and King in (or of) germany".

In German:

> erwählter Römischer Kayser, zu allen Zeiten Mehrer des Reichs, 
>   in Germanien.... König,

"Elected Emperor of the Romans, in all times Enlarger of the Realm, King in Germany".

http://eurulers.altervista.org/emperors.html[3](http://eurulers.altervista.org/emperors.html)

In my opinion emperor, *empereur*, *emperador*, *imperador*, etc. based on *imperator*, and *kaiser*, *tsar*, etc. based on *Caesar* are equally valid or invalid words for emperor, since they are all single words based on single words that are part of the full phrase *imperator caesar augustus* which might be considered necessary to fully give the title of the Roman emperor.  The fact that the Holy Roman Emperors believed themselves to be Roman emperors is why they often and usually used both *imperator* and *augustus* in their Latin titles.

Of course the single words like "emperor", *kaiser*, and *tsar*, etc., etc., are quite sufficient for the lesser 18th, 19th and 20th century monarchs of Russia, France, Austria, Haiti, Mexico, Brazil, Germany, India, Bulgaria, and Central Africa, showing that in rank they were some sort of "sub emperors", at least one rank lower than the Roman, "Byzantine" and Holy Roman Emperors.

Comment: Though you make valid observations, this doesn't actually answer the question of why/how the Caesar was borrowed into the German language as a translation for Imperator instead of, well, Imperator. This is especailly jarring when considering the official titles used by the German emperors were Imperator and Augustus, but not Caesar.

Comment: The point of calling yourself Emperor or Kaiser is that you 1. stand in continuation/tradition with Rome 2. That you are *not* sub-X to anyone, but *princeps*; at least equivalent to the highest available (ultimately your *peers* in power/nobility) 3. the late development inflation of these titles (you forget US, American Emperor Norton) is quite disconnected to explaining history and preference of Kaiser over Augustus?

Comment: Thanks for your very educating long answer! But as a matter of fact Kaiser has become a single word title, at least in common tongue. So why and how the cognomen of Julius, is the question. Mostly answered here already I think. And I won't confuse this by asking why Japan still has an "emperor"! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very detailed discussion of this whole complex here:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/german-kaiser-russian-tsar-arabic-qay%E1%B9%A3ar.3163959/

I will not repeat the whole argument. The gist of the discussion is that the use of derivatives of "Caesar" by German and Russian potentates in the middle ages has a lot to do with the "give unto Caesar" pericope in the New Testament. But read it for yourself.

Comment: That pericope seems to inform the thread starter in this discussion forum. I don't see how this is "the gist of it"?